# Backbone ID double-increment and wrong start

Tags: backbone.js, uniqueidentifier

I have a model that looks like this:

```
var TodosModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: null,
        content: 'Something Todo',
        completed: false
    },

    url: function() { return 'api/'+this.id; }

});
```

I'm adding models via:

```
var todoID = _.uniqueId();
var todoContent = this.newTodoField.val();
var todoCompleted = false;
  // Ensure there's something to save
        if(todoContent.length>0){
            var _this = this;
            // Create model
            var todo = new TodosModel({
                id: todoID,
                content: todoContent,
                completed: todoCompleted
            });
            todo.save({}, {
                wait: true,
                success: function(model, response) {
                    // Let the events deal with rendering...
                    _this.collection.add(model);
                },
                error: function(model, response) {
                    console.log('Could not create todo');
                }
            });
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that for some reason every id is double incremented - so if I start with no elements I get 1,3,5,7...

Which holds alright, except if I reload and those ID's are brought in from the API, and then the next generated _.uniqueID is based on the count rendered out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, here's the full code: http://sandbox.fluidbyte.org/todos/js/todos.js

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167138/backbone-underscore-uniqueid-odd-numbers/13168219 ?